# PHP. Strip_tags(): exclude <img> doesnt work in second parameter, images still stripped

Tags: php

I want to use the strip_tags on the html in the output and exclude some tags.
The problem is when i explude img tags, the image is still filtered by the strip_tags(). What can be the problem/solution?

My code:

```
 $result[0]['content'] = strip_tags ($result[0]['content'], '<h1><h2><h3><p><img><b>');
```

my image html:

```
<p><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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" type="jpg"></p>
```

Comment: Could you include the full html you're trying to filter? The strip_tags on that single string works just fine.

Comment: i changed it to the full string now

Comment: Maybe it's something with the base64 encoded `src`, but I can't see why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit, what you can try to at least get it to work:**

Replace the `<img` with `&lt;img` ( or another place holder if you think `&lt;img` might occur elsewhere in the content ). Then strip_tags and replace it back.

I know it isn't the best of solutions, but I'll keep trying to find out why this is happening in the first place, as I'm curious as well...

---

What PHP version are you using?

All the tests below work for me on 5.4.16 and 5.5:

```
$sHtml = '<p><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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" type="jpg"></p>';

echo '<h2>img</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo str_replace('<', '&lt;', strip_tags($sHtml, '<img>'));
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h2>p</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo str_replace('<', '&lt;', strip_tags($sHtml, '<p>'));
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h2>p,img</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo str_replace('<', '&lt;', strip_tags($sHtml, '<p><img>'));
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h2>h1,h2,h3,p,img,b</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
echo str_replace('<', '&lt;', strip_tags($sHtml, '<h1><h2><h3><p><img><b>'));
echo '</pre>';
```

---

**Edit: disregard below, it's not tagname which is too long, it's an attribute. My Fault!**

Could it possible have anything to do with: *Tag names within the input HTML that are greater than 1023 bytes in length will be treated as though they are invalid, regardless of the allowable_tags parameter.* ( taken from https://www.php.net/strip_tags )

Comment: Hmmm, well, that might be part of the problem then. Anyway you can upgrade php? ( which I highly recommend ;) ) does the proposed solution work for you?